# .get() callback accepting multiple parameters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am building a comics/artwork website that will let you search for material. The website will have two sub sites, comics and artwork. When the user selects a sub site, it will only display those images (comics or artwork). When they search, I'd also like to pass in a "sub site" parameter which will return either comics or artwork.

Therefore, for my search functionality, I'd like to pass multiple parameters to the search function- (search string, subsite).

I have the following search box: (how do I pass in subsite to the html search?)

```
$subsite = (isset($_GET['subsite']) ? ($_GET['subsite']) : null);
<span class="search"><input type="text" onkeyup="search(this.value)" name="input" value="" /></span>
```

That input is passed to this JQuery:

```
function search() {     
$.get("./scripts/search.php", {"_input" : $('input[name=input]').val(), "_subsite" : $('input[name=subsite]').val()},
    function(returned_data) {
                $("#output").html(returned_data);
    }
);
}
```

PHP: Search.php

```
$input = (isset($_GET['_input']) ? ($_GET['_input']) : 0); 

$subsite = (isset($_GET['_subsite']) ? ($_GET['_subsite']) : null);
echo "SEARCH SITE = " . $subsite;
//This echos out nothing... it should be the subsite, either "artwork" or "comics"
```

I'm trying to get my comics website to go live, but I can't get this to work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span class="search">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="search(this.value)" name="input" value="" />
    <input id="subsite" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subsite; ?>">
</span>
```

.

```
function search(value) {
    var subsite = $("#subsite").val();  
    $.get("./scripts/search.php", { _input : value, _subsite : subsite },
        function(returned_data) {
                    $("#output").html(returned_data);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know your jQuery wasn't going to be parsed by PHP. This should work in that case.